# Finding the condition on a variable under which a circle passes through the points of intersection of two other circles and another fixed point

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

The following is a problem from the chapter "Circles":

> If P and Q are the points of intersection of the circles $x^2+y^2+3x+7y+2p-5=0$ and $x^2+y^2+2x+2y-p^2=0$, then there is a circle passing through P, Q and $(1,1)$ for:
>
> (A) all values of $p$
>
> (B) all except one value of $p$
>
> (C) all except two values of $p$
>
> (D) exactly one value of $p$

**My Attempt:**

The family of circles passing though the point of intersection of the two given circles is given by the following equation:

$$(x^2+y^2+3x+7y+2p-5)+\lambda(x^2+y^2+2x+2y-p^2)=0$$

One of the circles represented by the above equation passes through the point $(1,1)$. So,

$$(1^2+1^2+3(1)+7(1)+2p-5)+\lambda(1^2+1^2+2(1)+2(1)-p^2)=0$$

$$(7+2p)+\lambda(6-p^2)=0$$

We know that there exists only one circle which passes through three fixed points. So, there must exist a unique value of $\lambda$ for the circle to exist. The final equation can be converted in such a way we obtain an expression for $\lambda$ as follows:

$$\lambda=\frac{2p+7}{p^2-6}$$

So for $\lambda$ to exist $p^2-6\neq0$ or $p\neq \pm \sqrt6$

So from this, I concluded that there is a circle passing through the points P,Q, and $(1,1)$ for **all except two values of $p$** i.e., option (C). But surprisingly the answer given in my book is (A) all values of $p$. I checked the solution, but there is no reason specified for this.

The following image is the solution from one of the web resources for the same problem (which is of no use):

[image]

Almost all resources state the answer for the given problem is "all values of $p$". So clearly, I think I've made a mistake. But I am unable to figure where I went wrong. Kindly explain which option is correct and the reason for it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

> The family of circles passing though the point of intersection of the
>   two given circles is given by the following equation:
>
> $$(x^2+y^2+3x+7y+2p-5)+\lambda(x^2+y^2+2x+2y-p^2)=0$$

This omits the circle $x^2+y^2+2x+2y-p^2=0$ (corresponding to $\lambda=\infty$ in your equation). And in fact if you put $p=\pm\sqrt 6$, it is easy to check that this circle passes through $P,Q$ and $(1,1)$ as long as $P$ and $Q$ exist (i.e. as long as the original two circles intersect).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it must be $\lambda \to \infty$ instead of $\lambda=\infty$, but I understood your answer. I also think we can also explain $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ when $\lambda \to \infty$ as $\mu S_1+S_2=0$ when $\mu=0$. So, in order to avoid such mistakes in future, I must be checking whether the component circles ($S_1=0$ and $S_2=0$) also belong the new family of circles ($S_1+\lambda S_2=0$). Am I right?

Comment: No, I did mean $\lambda=\infty$. $\lambda\to\infty$ makes no sense here (whereas $\lambda=\infty$ _kind of_ makes sense). And in order to avoid such mistakes, you must remember that the formula $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$ for such a family of circles is deficient $-$ it doesn't give you all possible circles. One way to remedy this is to use the formula $\lambda S_1+(1-\lambda)S_2$ instead.

Comment: Thank you. I understood the second part of your comment (*which is quite similar to what I suggested with the use of $\lambda$ and $\mu$*). But, it would be great if you could explain, how $\lambda=\infty$ "*kind* of makes sense" here, as I've learnt the other way round in Calculus. ($\infty$ cannot be attained it can only be approached towards, or simply a number can approach $\infty$ but it can't be equal to it)

Comment: @Intellex: that's my point, really $-$ your equation is _not_ a full solution, precisely because $\lambda$ can never equal $\infty$. When I said it kind of made sense, I meant that it was obvious what I meant by it, not that it had a rigorous mathematical meaning.